# DropDownList Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting a validation error message on my DropDownList within my Create Action if I click the submit button without selecting a value from the DropDownList.

The validation error that I'm getting is **The value "" is invalid**. I would like the validation error message to say **State is required!** instead.

I added the required validation attribute to the StId property on the ViewModel but that did not resolve the issue.

**Customer Model**

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustLastName { get; set; }

    public int StId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

**State Model**

```
    public class State
{
    public int StId { get; set; }
    public string StAbbr { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerFormViewModel**

```
    public class CustomerFormViewModel
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string CustLastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int StId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
    public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private OneClickAwayDbContext _context;

    public CustomerController(OneClickAwayDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Customers.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var states = _context.States.ToList();
        var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
        {
            States = states
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomerFormViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var customer = new Customer();
            {
                customer.CustFirstName = vm.CustFirstName;
                customer.CustLastName = vm.CustLastName;
                customer.StId = vm.StId;
            }

            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        else
        {
            var stateViewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
            {
                States = _context.States.ToList()
            };
            return View("Create", stateViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

**Create.chtml**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustFirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustFirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustFirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustLastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustLastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustLastName)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(s => s.StId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.StId, new SelectList(Model.States, "StId", "StAbbr"), "", new { @class="form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.StId)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown will display _State is required!_

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, You would think it would since I added `[Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required!")]` but it only displays **The value "" is invalid**

Comment: It will (I have just tested it) so its something you have not shown us. And as a side note, in your `else` block it should be just `vm.States = _context.States.ToList(); return View(vm);` (no  need to initialize a new view model - just return the one you posted

Comment: I inspected the DropDownList using Chrome Developer tools and this is what it shows 

`<select class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="State is required!" id="StId" name="StId"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">PA</option>
<option value="2">OH</option>
<option value="3">WV</option>
</select>`

`<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="StId" data-valmsg-replace="true">The value '' is invalid.</span>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you for that side note in my else block.

Comment: First, the fact the your `<span class="field-validation-error" ...>` element does not include an inner `<span for="StId" generated="true" class="">State is required!</span>` element means you have not implemented client side validation. And the default server side validation cannot generate that error. It is something else in your code that is causing the issue

Comment: Want to make sure that you have included jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: @Ravi A, I was just looking at how to implement clientside validation in my project. I assumed that clientside validation was already enabled but I was wrong. Trying to figure out how to implement the client side validation now but not having any luck.

Comment: state is required! is returning from your above code. you are wondering for client side validation?

Comment: @LateshtClick, It appears that when i click Save there is a post to the server and client side validation must not be enabled, I thought client side validation was enabled by default. Having trouble figuring out how to enable client side validation to see if that fixes the issue I'm having.

Comment: You are doing everything right. Please include jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js in your cshtml file something like this <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Ravi A, I added the following 2 lines to the _Layout.cshtml file, my js scripts are in that location and not inside a Scripts folder.

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`


    `<script src="@Url.Content("~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"‌​)" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`

Comment: @Ravi A, when I add the following above and run the code I get this error

`Unexpected character '‌'` for both of the <script> tags that I added in the _Layout.cshtml file`

Comment: One thing I have noticed in your generated HTML is missing data-val-number attribute. For a property being int this should have been there. Can you check if the property name is same as the ones in your database.Also when you submit is your post method getting hit ? if yes is ModelState.IsValid true?

Comment: @Ravi A, I set a breakpoint on `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and when I ran my code and clicked on the save button without adding any values my ModelState.IsValid value is False. The int value is a Foreign Key if that helps.

Comment: The fact that there is postback confirms that client side validation is not happening.Make sure the script lines are added at the beginning of the layout file.

Comment: @Ravi A., I was able to get this to work with your suggestion on adding the `<script>` tags. I only needed to add the following `<script>` to the Create.cshtml file that contains the form rather than add it to the `_layout.cshtml` for all pages to load. I only had to add `@section scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
}`

I did not need to add anything to the web.config file either.

Comment: That's great! I have added it as answer would be good if you accept it as answer for others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js in your cshtml file

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></scri‌​pt>     
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.uno‌​btrusive.js"></scrip‌​t>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

include following jquery file in your layout page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Using this your submit button click event is not going to your [HttpPost] Action of your view if any validation are required.

Comment: run your project and in browser press Ctrl+Shift+I (right click and open inspect element) and in source tab check your loaded jquery file.

Comment: In which web.config you changed is important. You have to change in root folder web.config file, not that which is in View folder(that is for that folder only).

Comment: This does not answer the question  It just shows how to include the scripts for client side validation (which is a good idea) but does not address OP's claim (which cannot be answered anyway since the code OP has shown does not add that error)

Comment: @LateshtClick, I only have 1 web.config file which is located in the root of my application. Also, I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core which does not include a "Scripts" folder. Also, when you open the web.config file it suggest placing application settings in the appsettings.json file. I still did as you suggested with the web.config and added both `<script>` tags to the layout page along with the create.cshtml page but still no luck.